# UINavigationController interactivePopGestureRecognizer working abnormal in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

In iOS7, we have a new "swipe left to right" gesture, this is a very useful feature, but now I have a problem with it.

I use this code to custom the back button in `UINavigationBar`.

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];`

but this will disables the "swipe left to right" gesture, so I use the follow code to keep the gesture enabled.

`self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`

And then, I found that the gesture is working abnormal, if current ViewController has a tableView, when the tableView is scrolling, the gesture won't be triggered. Now the gesture can't be triggered easily, is there some way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to implement: ´– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:´ on your ´UIGestureRecognizerDelegate´ then you can check if one of the gestures is the swipetopop gesture and return YES.

Comment: @PeterSegerblom It works! And I implemented - `(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`, `return YES;` to disable the otherGestureRecognizer, so the current ViewController won't receive the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for scrolling `UITableView`. Now it looks well, thank you very much!

Comment: Swift 3 solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/308315

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This code can wroks well for me.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.class];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` to `self` is only the first step. The second step is to implement

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return !(otherGestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer)
}
```

The test against the pan gesture recognizer is needed to block vertical scrolling of a scroll or table view while the interactive pop is in progress.

Comment: This code won't trigger `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` when `UITableView` is scrolling, I implement `- (BOOL)shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`, and `return YES;`.

Answer (score 5):

Add in Class Controller "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate"

in viewDidAppear add

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate =  self
}
```

=)

Comment: Not required in ```ViewDidAppear``` method.