# Slide gesture with custom back button freezes the root view controller

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have custom back buttons all over my app and it looks like navigation controller does not like it.

So, I want the iOS7 swipe-to-go-back gesture to work along with my custom back buttons. Searched and tried different ways but none seems to be promising. The closest I could get is with http://keighl.com/post/ios7-interactive-pop-gesture-custom-back-button/.
However, Now when I keep pushing and popping the navigation stack, after sometime the rootViewController in the stack stops responding to any touch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That link is dead?

Answer (score 6):

Subclassing UINavigationController, like keighl is suggesting, is the right approach imo. But he's missing a check for the root view controller to avoid freezing when the gesture is executed on the root view.
Here's a modified version with the additional check:

CBNavigationController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CBNavigationController : UINavigationController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@end
```

CBNavigationController.m:

```
#import "CBNavigationController.h"

@interface CBNavigationController ()
@end

@implementation CBNavigationController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    __weak CBNavigationController *weakSelf = self;

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
    {
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = weakSelf;
        self.delegate = weakSelf;
    }
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

#pragma mark UINavigationControllerDelegate

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);

    // Enable the gesture again once the new controller is shown AND is not the root view controller
    if (viewController == self.viewControllers.firstObject)
    {
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
            self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
            self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

Comment: That should be marked as proper answer - only one that works properly for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem, here is my solution:
In your custom NavigationController, like `MYNavigationController`, cause you set the gesture delegate to the navigationController, you can add the delegate method there :

```html
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if (self.viewControllers.count>1) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

then it will stop the poping action when it's in the root viewController and avoiding the freezing behavior.

Comment: That doesn't work - you can still cause a freeze when you keep swiping when animation is happening

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem, I have fix it by modifying code provide in the link which you are referring . Now My screens freezes very rarely still finding for permanent fix.

```
@implementation PPNavigationController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     __weak PPNavigationController *weakSelf = self;

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
    {
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = weakSelf;
        self.delegate = weakSelf;
    }

}



-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    // Enable the gesture again once the new controller is shown

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = viewController;
}

Don't use this method
//-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
//}
```

Comment: Hey Anand, I have tried the above code previously and it does make the situation a little better. But when you push and pop from the navigation stack a lot then the screen still freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066088/custom-uibackbuttonitem-and-uinavigationcontroller-gestures)

You can use a little trick to get the native gesture working.
Create a subclass of `UINavigationItem`, then override `leftBarButtonItems` method:

```
- (NSArray*)leftBarButtonItems
{
    return nil;
}
```

Now use this class for the item that has custom left `UIBarButtonItem`. The gesture works! This is because `UINavigationController` thinks there are no left items and enables the gesture. You are still able to access your custom item through the `leftBarButtonItem` property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Swift subclass of `UINavigationController` you can use that I adapted from @weak's answer. There shouldn't be a need to implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` as the nav delegate's `navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)` handles the work of enabling and disabling the pop gesture.

Using this subclass in your storyboard or code is easier than doing a one-off disabling in your other controllers that are embedded in nav controllers.

```
import UIKit

@objc class LWNavigationController : UINavigationController,
                                     UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController,
                                     animated: Bool) {
        // Disable this gesture while animating a push.
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        debugPrint("------\(#function) \(viewController)------")
    }

    // MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              didShow viewController: UIViewController,
                              animated: Bool) {
        if (viewController == self.viewControllers.first) {
            // Keep the gesture disabled if we're at the root to avoid back swipes
            // from corrupting the navigation stack.
            self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        }
        debugPrint("------\(#function) \(viewController) " +
                   "enabled: \(self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled)" +
                   "------")
    }
}
```