# Wrong swipe direction in navigation in Right to Left

Tags: ios, objective-c, right-to-left

I disable views rotation (process when Hebrew language is selected and all views change their positions from left to right) when phone has RightToLeft localization:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")){
    if (RightToLeft) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, but I need to swipe right-to-left to return in previous view controller.
How can I set left to right swipe direction for navigation between ViewControllers?

Comment: is your question about swipe gesture? what does the code represent? it is not related to swipe.please provide the correct code snippet

Comment: I disable RightToLeft rotation in my view controller by this code, but it doesn't solve problem with swipe direction, when we want to return back.

Comment: Hi, did you set this because you always wanted your view in portrait mode?

Comment: No, I did it because I wanted the same view's position even when language set in Hebrew

Comment: @Konstantin.Efimenko I am looking for the same. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Try this answer and let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48383893/1953178

Comment: @Konstantin.Efimenko Did you find a working solution?

Answer (score 6):

I finally got one working for those who subclassed the `UINavigationController` class. You should do something like this :

```
final class TestNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
         navigationController.view.semanticContentAttribute = UIView.isRightToLeft() ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
         navigationController.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = UIView.isRightToLeft() ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
    }
}

extension UIView {

    static func isRightToLeft() -> Bool {
        return UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute == .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

Dynamically, your NavigationController will adapt to the forced semantic content attribute. I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it after searching long time, if someone seeks.

The previous answer may cause the UI to hang / freeze.

The reason that the UI freezes / hangs is because the UINavigationController is missing a check for the root view controller when the gesture is executed on the root view. There a few ways to fix that, the following is what I did.

You should subclass UINavigationController, this is the right way to go and add implement as followed:

```
class RTLNavController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //  Adding swipe to pop viewController
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self

        //  UINavigationControllerDelegate
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        navigationController.view.semanticContentAttribute = UIView.isRightToLeft() ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
        navigationController.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = UIView.isRightToLeft() ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
    }

    //  Checking if the viewController is last, if not disable the gesture
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if self.viewControllers.count > 1 {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
}

extension UIView {
    static func isRightToLeft() -> Bool {
        return UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute == .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

***Resources:***

Original question:

- [Slide gesture with custom back button freezes the root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051350/slide-gesture-with-custom-back-button-freezes-the-root-view-controller)

The answer is used for the solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27683249/1138498

Other solution which may work better (But it's in Objective-C):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364126/1138498

And of course using some of this question ideas.