# Change interactivePopGestureRecognizer direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, interactivepopgesture

My app supports both English and Arabic. `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` works properly when using English, ie on swiping from left to right, it pops viewController. But when i am using arabic, I have changed the `semanticContentAttribute` from right to left.

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LanguageCode"] isEqualToString:@"en"])
    {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];       //View for English language
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];       //mirror view for Arabic language
    }
```

But the `interactivePopGestureRecogniser` is still from left to right. How can I change the direction of `interactivePopGestureRecogniser` such that it supports Arabic? I want to swipe from right to left to pop view controller on using Arabic language.

Comment: remove the app from memory and start again, this time the swipe direction should be ok.

Comment: Did you find any solution that works?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for it after searching long time, if someone seeks.

The previous answer may cause the UI to hang / freeze.

The reason that the UI freezes / hangs is because the UINavigationController is missing a check for the root view controller when the gesture is executed on the root view. There a few ways to fix that, the following is what I did.

You should subclass UINavigationController, this is the right way to go and add implement as followed:

```
class RTLNavController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //  Adding swipe to pop viewController
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self

        //  UINavigationControllerDelegate
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        navigationController.view.semanticContentAttribute = UIView.isRightToLeft() ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
        navigationController.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = UIView.isRightToLeft() ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
    }

    //  Checking if the viewController is last, if not disable the gesture
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if self.viewControllers.count > 1 {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
}

extension UIView {
    static func isRightToLeft() -> Bool {
        return UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute == .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

***Resources:***

Original question:

- [Slide gesture with custom back button freezes the root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051350/slide-gesture-with-custom-back-button-freezes-the-root-view-controller)

The answer is used for the solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27683249/1138498

Other solution which may work better (But it's in Objective-C):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364126/1138498

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trials, the only solution worked for me was this:

**Swift 3**:

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

You can exclude the semantic attribute for certain types like:

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```