# Interactive default UINavigationController transition

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I want to make the default push and pop animations of `UINavigationController` interactive, just like the swipe from the left side of the screen gesture does. These transitions will be driven by gesture recognizers.

There's a lot of info online about making custom animations interactive using `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`, but I'm simply looking to make the default transitions interactive. As far as I can tell, this can't be done using this method.

How do I make these transitions interactive, without messing with the default animations?

Comment: May be you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35510861/1378447

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a few days investigating this very issue and I was only able to get interactive transitions using `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` with the delegate providing the 'to' and 'from' transitions.

This makes sense as to interpolate between your transitions automatically from 0 to 1 on both animations, it specifically needs both Transition Controllers declared to do this and the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` does not provide a method to access both as far as I can tell.