# iOS / Swift - Swipe/Drag between ViewControllers like Telegram/iOS Settings

Tags: ios, swift

so I already searched a lot but maybe I missed something.
I would want to be able to drag a view to the side and drag a new view from the left.

Like in Telegram where you can slide between chats overview and a chat itself or in the iOS Settings where you can slide right and drag the detail view to the right and the overview is coming from the left.

I do know how to do segues with a slide animation, that's not what I am asking. These segues are started ones and can not be controlled by the user.

Comment: "in the iOS Settings where you can slide right and drag the detail view to the right and the overview is coming from the left." - This is just default `UINavigationController` behaviour. Are you sure this is what you mean?

Comment: @AlexCornforth yes I just was not sure and I did not get it to work yet, but I guess I now understood, thanks

Comment: try using this in your initial viewcontroller `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self` so when you push VC using right swipe from left side of the screen you can able to go back. like iOS settings does.

Comment: Check https://github.com/serp1412/LazyTransitions and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35510861/5790492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use a navigation controller behind my bottom bar controller so I had the wrong transitions. When using the native Navigation Controller on all subviews of the bottom bar navigation controller you can control toolbar items and the "slide" I mentioned.