# Enable back back swipe gesture when using custom navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I've got a custom navigation controller declared as below. My problem is that once I implement this, the back swipe gesture to go back to previous stack (interactivepopgesturerecognizer) is not working. How can I enable it back? I've got a lot of view controller in my app. Thank You.

```
    #import "NavController.h"

    @interface NavController ()
    {
        BOOL shouldIgnorePushingViewControllers;
    }

    @end

    @implementation NavController

    -(instancetype)init {
        self = [super init];
        self.delegate=self;

        return self;

    }

    -(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        if (!shouldIgnorePushingViewControllers)
        {
            [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
        }

        shouldIgnorePushingViewControllers = YES;
    }

    - (void)didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        shouldIgnorePushingViewControllers = NO;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Take a hint here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23604864/1463604

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable property

`self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;`

to `init` method